# Can Data studio be integrated with helpshift?

Tags: looker-studio, helpshift

I'm looking to integrate Helpshift program with Data Studio.
Is this possible?
If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is Helpshift, but Data Studio can be integrated with any data source that can be accessed publicly using [Community Connectors](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector).

The question is if there is already a Community Connector developed by someone or not.  Considering that's not the case, if Helpshift provides an API interface, you may want to develop your own.  This will require some effort and programming skills in JavaScript.